# Pandas: Selecting multiple rows by list of partial keys

Tags: python, pandas, select, indexing, multi-index

I have a table with a multi-column (i.e. hierarchical) index, like this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'x0', 'v', 1], 
    ['a', 'x1', 'w', 2], 
    ['b', 'x0', 'y', 3], 
    ['b', 'x1', 'z', 4], 
], columns = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'val']).set_index(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
```

Now, I can select a list of full keys, like this:

```
a.loc[[('a', 'x0', 'v'), ('b', 'x1', 'z')]]
```

which returns the expected result, i.e. a data frame with two rows (values 1 and 4).

However, when I try the same with partial keys, like this:

```
a.loc[[('a', 'x0'), ('b', 'x1')]]
```

Then I get the right keys, but the val column shows all NaN values. What's wrong here?

Similarly, I can select several keys of the first level:

```
a.loc[['a', 'b']]
```

which works just fine. When I try those a tuples however:

```
a.loc[[('a',), ('b',)]]
```

Then I get the NaN values again.

EDIT: I'm looking to get the output starting with the key combinations I enter, not the slice, i.e. with this:

```
a.loc[[('a', 'x0'), ('b', 'x1')]]
```

I wanted this output:

```
                val
key1 key2 key3     
a    x0   v       1
b    x1   z       4
```

But what I get is this:

```
                val
key1 key2 key3     
a    x0   v       NaN
b    x1   z       NaN
```

So, clearly, the right indices are selected, but why do I not get any values?

Comment: Have you looked at [cross-section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)?

Comment: Edited the description: I'm not looking to slice a range of values, but do a narrower selection

Comment: What happened to the answer that someone posted? Did you see it before it was deleted? It suggested using [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17464

Comment: Weird. I have tried to solve your problem but I experience not very intuitive behavior.  E.g. `a.loc[(('a', 'x0'), ('b', 'x1')), :]` produces `val \n key1 key2 key3 \n a    x1   w       2`.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I've found so far is this:

```
pd.concat([a.loc[key] for key in [
    ('a', 'x0'), ('b', 'x1')
]], axis=0)
```

It doesn't seem optimal and is a bit slow, but at least I get the correct results. So if you have better solutions, please post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.loc()` is not able to do combinations of partial keys. If you try to have multiple values it will join all rows containing any of the values. Because of that, `a.loc[['a','b'], :, :]` (or `a.loc[['a','b']]` which gives the same result in this particular case) works and returns all rows where `key1` is either `'a'` or `'b'`.

However, trying to use different values for different keys will lead to an or of all values, such that `a.loc[['a','b'], ['x0', 'x1']]` returns all combinations of `key1` being `'a'` or `'b'` and `key2` being `'x0'` or `'x1'`.  When you instead try to use an incomplete combination in a tuple, as `a.loc[[('a', 'x0'), ('b', 'x1')]]` it assumes `('a', 'x0')` and `('b', 'x1')` to be complete keys. But these do not exist (of course) so `NaN` (for not available)  is returned as output.

Thus, to select multiple partial keys you are destined to use another method. One way is to do it the way you propose, by trying the partial keys one by one and then concatenate the result. Another approach is to use `.select()` instead, to find exactly the items you are interested in. That, however, is a bit complicated, since it requires a function that returns `True` for the rows with the proper keys.

A possible implementation of it is:

```
sel_a_x0 = lambda row: row[0] == 'a' and row[1] == 'x0'
sel_b_x1 = lambda row: row[0] == 'b' and row[1] == 'x1'
sel_combined = lambda row: sel_a_x0(row) or sel_b_x1(row)
a.select(sel_combined)
```

This can of course be implemented in a more dense way, where everything is combined to a single line, but that gets pretty messy:

```
a.select(lambda row: (row[0] == 'a' and row[1] == 'x0') or (row[0] == 'b' and row[1] == 'x1'))
```

so I would prefer to keep the sub-expressions separated.

Also, I have not timed or compared this approach to the one you suggest yourself, so I don't know if it is any quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove all unnecessary levels by [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and compare with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) for boolean mask:

```
idx = [('a', 'x0'), ('b', 'x1')]

mask = a.index.droplevel(2).isin(idx)
```

---

```
mask = a.reset_index(level=2, drop=True).index.isin(idx)

print (mask)
[ True False False  True]
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = a[mask]
print (df)
                val
key1 key2 key3     
a    x0   v       1
b    x1   z       4
```